# VirtualBox 7 ubuntu - cannot configure two monitors

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, multiple-monitors

I have just upgraded to VirtualBox 7.0.10 from VirtualBox 6.1.
Host system is Ubuntu 22.04.

I am unable to configure two monitors for my Windows 10 virtual machine.
When I do so, I can see windows loading screen for a while. After that the screen turns black and the only thing to do is using "power off the machine" option.
When I set monitor count to 1 in settings-> display - I can run the VM normally.
I did not encounter such a problems with previous version of VirtualBox.

Of course, I have updated the Guest Additions to the corresponding version.

Is that any trick to allow using two monitors setup with VirtualBox 7.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug in an early Virtual Box 7 build.
Now I am with 7.0.12 and I do not face the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  I was able access the desktop using Real VNC and once the displays were configured to "extend" everything works as it should.

Hope this helps.